# abc package doesn't work

Tags: abc

I I use a piece of latex to illustrate the package abc, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[generate,ps2eps]{abc}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
This is an Irish reel:
\begin{abc}[name=julia,program={abcm2ps -O=}]
X:63
T: Julia Delaney's
M: C|
L: 1/8
R: reel
K: Ddor
|: dcAG ˜F2EF|˜E2 DE FD D2|dcAG FGAA|Addc d2 fe :|
f2fe fagf |ecgc acgc |f2fe fagf|edcG Add2 :|
\end{abc}
This is an Irish polka, slighly smaller:
End of document.
\end{document}
```

but the result shows a square with the track name.
[image]
and I just get the following error back
"Process started
'abcm2ps' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

```
Input files: out-abc-1.ps Processing: out-abc-1.ps

ps2eps: Can't open out-abc-1.ps: No such file or directory

epstopdf ($Id: epstopdf.pl 66407 2023-03-06 23:44:49Z karl $) 2.31 !!! Error: Cannot open out-abc-1.eps: No such file or
directory

C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:921: command failed with exit code 2: perl.exe c:\texlive\2023\texmf dist\scripts\epstopdf epstopdf.pl
out-abc-1.eps
```

Comment: Welcome. // When the program `ps2eps` is found, but the file `out-abc-1.ps` is not, it may be a configuration problem. Or you may have, like I sometimes do, have opened a previous result e.g. in Adobe Reader ... then latex can't write an output, until I close that viewer.

Comment: Have you installed `abcm2ps`?

Comment: I downloaded https://github.com/lewdlime/abcm2ps but i have no idea how to install it